# How to run tcl code in r

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have used SpecTcl which a WYSIWYG GUI-Builder for Tcl/Tk (http://sourceforge.net/projects/spectcl/) to create a gui, which has the output as tcl code. How can I use this gui in R script?

Comment: There's a Tcl/Tk package for R on CRAN. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tcltk2/index.html

Comment: Tcl/Tk is built-in to most versions of R. You can check whether it's in your system using `capabilities('tcltk')` and, if so, load the built-in package using `library('tcltk')`. @user2633645 That package is an add-on and does not provide the main bindings to tcl/tk.

Comment: Also, we can't help you if we have no idea what that file is, where it comes from, or what its output is.